# Convert slot to timestamp in Geyser

Tags: geyser, slots

I currently run a Geyser plugin and it sends slot alongside every account. Is there a reliable way to determine when the slot occurred? When the plugin boots up, it sends all accounts since genesis. In order to save timestamps in my system, I need a way to convert those slots to some sort of datetime. I could make an JSON-RPC call to get this information but would like to avoid that if at all possible.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using bigtable or a local NAS to send the accounts at bootup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stream blocks too, they have a `block_time` field.  From that you can link the `block_time` to account update `slot`s.  It may be necessary to backfill via RPC for account updates that occurred prior to the slot of the accounts snapshot that the validator was started from.

Comment: O, WHAT?! I had no idea this existed. Amazing. Any examples/docs you can point me to?

Comment: Yeah. You want to override [this method](https://docs.rs/solana-geyser-plugin-interface/latest/solana_geyser_plugin_interface/geyser_plugin_interface/trait.GeyserPlugin.html#method.notify_block_metadata) which streams you [these](https://docs.rs/solana-geyser-plugin-interface/latest/solana_geyser_plugin_interface/geyser_plugin_interface/struct.ReplicaBlockInfo.html)